# JavaScript Regex: Make ungreedy

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex which looks for `%{any charactering including new lines}%`:

```
/[%][{]\s*((.|\n|\r)*)\s*[}][%]/gm
```

If I test the regex on a string like "%{hey}%", the regex returns "hey" as a match.

However, if I give it "%{hey}%%{there}%", it doesn't match both "hey" and "there" seperately, it has one match—"hey}%%{there".

How do I make it ungreedy to so it returns a match for each %{}%?

Comment: As I always mention on Regular expression questions, check out Regexr,  a cool Flash Based Regex tool, by gSkinner Link: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ There is also the AS3 Regular Expression tester: http://www.idsklijnsma.nl/regexps/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a question mark after the star.

```
/[%][{]\s*((.|\n|\r)*?)\s*[}][%]/gm
```

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, to make a wildcard match non-greedy, just append it with `?` (so `*?` instead of `*` and `+?` instead of `+`).

Secondly, your pattern can be simplified in a number of ways.

```
/%\{\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*\}%/gm
```

There's no need to put a single character in square brackets.

Lastly the expression in the middle you want to capture, you'll note I put `[\s\S]`. That comes from [Matching newlines in JavaScript](http://simonwillison.net/2004/Sep/20/newlines/) as a replacement for the `DOTALL` behaviour.

Comment: *I* certainly don't see any reason for a downvote.  Simply adding the question mark as Anton did may have solved the immediate problem, but this answer is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter and faster working:

```
/%\{([^}]*)\}%/gm
```

Comment: That's not quite as broad. It's simple and fast but won't cover cases like `%{some}test}%` that the other answers will. Whether or not that's better or worse depends on an assumption the OP hasn't specified however.